# Reflective floor and glossy material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am working on a dice. That dice is placed on a white reflective floor. The reflective floor has a big impact on the look of the dice:

[image]

After removing the reflective floor I got this:

[image]

**Question:**

Is it possible to add the reflective floor again and preserve the plastic look of the dice (so no floor reflections on the dice) ?? I work with cycles.

After reading the answer of Faceb I unchecked Glossy in Ray visibility. The result is in the image below. Now I have a dice with a nice plastic look and a floor reflecting the dice but not changing the look of the dice. But now I have this black line "surrounding" the dice. Now ... how to get rid of that ?

[image]

Comment: Jan, don't forget our brains are used to seeing reflections on objects, especially on specular objects. Seeing some form of reflection helps us get a sense of the surface property of an object. Once you remove the reflections and the surrounding it becomes less realistic. Additionally the phenomenon of 'colour bleeding'  can be observed by putting a very brightly coloured object on a white surface, like a carrot on a sheet of a4 paper.

Comment: I agree with you but for this image I do not mind that. I don't want the floor have an impact on the look of the dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

- Select the floor
- Go to the *Properties* panel
- From the tabs, go to *Object* (looks like a cube)
- In *Ray Visibility*, click on *Glossy* check